# nginx rewrite rules remove following characters

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm not expert with rewrite and I get problem with nginx rewrite rule, I get URL:

www.mydomain.com/sales/reference/appartement-2-bedroom-city-miami/

I need to get final url like :
www.mydomain.com/hello/reference/

so I need remove all character between the last 2 /
I need to remove /apartement-2-bedroom/ and replace by only one /
Of course in this example I have /appartement-2-bedroom-city-miami/ but that never same, each url are different.

So many example below I would like:

www.mydomain.com/sales/ref-458/appartement-2-bedroom-city-miami/ must become:
www.mydomain.com/sales/ref-458/

other example:

www.mydomain.com/sales/ref-455/appartement-3-bedroom-with-terrace-city-miami/ must become:
www.mydomain.com/sales/ref-455/

Some help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear how complicated your URLs that need to be rewritten are, but using the two examples you give then if you place the following at the server level of your config it will do what you are saying:

```
rewrite ^(/sales/ref.+)/(.+) $1/ redirect;
```

This regex will catch any url beginning `/sales/refXXX/` with any number of characters after that and rewrite it to remove anything after `/sales/refXXX/`

`X` can be any character.

Comment: in fact I just know that the the ref will be a number, so the URL is : www.mydomain.com/sales/2018-45/appartement-3-bedroom-with-terrace-city-miami/, so in this case what will be the rewrite rule?

Comment: It will if you delete `ref` from it